# sorting 1-bit array using radix sort?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have a bool array "a flag array stored as char*"
I want to efficiently sort it using radix sort, what I understand is that radix sort complexity is O(#bits N) which will be O(8N) for char* and O(N) for a bool* (if it exists)

I've tried thrust::stable_sort_by_key, on my device sorting 2^21 char pointer takes 1.7 ms
another test was by using a compare function for the first bit only:

```
struct OBCmp {
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const char& o1, const char& o2) {
        return (o1 & 1) < (o2 & 1);
    }
};
```

the result time using `thrust::stable_sort_by_key(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), d_vec_values.begin(), OBCmp ());` was 9 ms

but I'm almost sure that it has used another algorithm "not radix sort", and my guess is that if I can make radix sort to use only the first bit, the time should be around 0.3 ms

any hint how to do this? "even manually without thrust"

Comment: Does sorting a bit-array even make sense? The entire data set can be characterized by its size and the number of `true`s. If you really need it sorted, I would go with a variation of quick sort. It will only need one pass and, therefore, is `O(n)`. But you should implement it yourself because your requirements are quite special. General sorting algorithms won't get max performance.

Comment: Why don't you just count the number of 1 (or 0) ?

Comment: sorting bit-array to avoid branching within warps
@matovitch explain more

Comment: Well if you count N char to one in your array of size M. Then your sorted array will only be N ones followed by M-N zeros (or else the reversed array).

Comment: How about if somebody (matovitch) provides an answer.  The sensible thing to do is to count the ones or zeroes.  Thrust [counting operations](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__counting.html) is one possibility

Comment: Is there any value to sorting when the container only allows zeros or ones?  There are probably other "bit twiddling" techniques to coalesce the ones and zeros together.  Search "bit twiddling" on the web.

Comment: isn't this similar to thrust::partition with a condition of x == 0? the performance was 2.2 ms

Comment: @RobertCrovella I'm happy with anyone providing an answer :)

Comment: `thrust::partition` and `thrust::sort` both have to move data.  `thrust::count` and `thrust::fill` don't do any data movement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest counting ones (or zeroes) and then creating the solution vector based on that.  Here's a worked example using thrust:

```
$ cat t427.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DSIZE (1<<21)
int main(){
  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  float et;
  cudaEventCreate(&start); cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  thrust::host_vector<char> h_data(DSIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < DSIZE; i++) h_data[i] = rand()%2;
  thrust::device_vector<char> d_data = h_data;
  cudaEventRecord(start);
  thrust::sort(d_data.begin(), d_data.end());
  cudaEventRecord(stop);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  printf("Sort time: %fms\n", et);
  thrust::device_vector<char> d2_data = h_data;
  thrust::device_vector<char> d3_data(DSIZE);
  cudaEventRecord(start);
  int zeroes = thrust::count(d2_data.begin(), d2_data.end(), 0);
  thrust::fill(d3_data.begin(), d3_data.begin()+zeroes, 0);
  thrust::fill(d3_data.begin() + zeroes, d3_data.end(), 1);
  cudaEventRecord(stop);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&et, start, stop);
  printf("count/fill time: %fms\n", et);
  if (thrust::equal(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), d3_data.begin())) printf("Success!\n");
  else printf("Failure\n");
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -o t427 t427.cu
$ ./t427
Sort time: 1.450560ms
count/fill time: 0.302656ms
Success!
$
```

Comment: Also note that I could just as easily have done the `thrust::fill` operations on the `d2_data` vector.

Answer (score 3):

In plain old ugly C ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

void sort(char* my_array, int size)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, counter += (my_array[i] == 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++, my_array[i] = 1);

    for (int i = counter; i < size; i++, my_array[i] = 0);
}

int main()
{
    char* my_array = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        my_array[i] = (((i + 43) * (i + 17)) % 677) & 1; //Thought less than 0.5s too garantee randomness of chosen numbers
    }

    sort(my_array, SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```